# Does the Angular Compiler optimize string expressions?

Tags: angular, angular-compiler

I have the following code snippet:

```
"foo".length > 0 ? true : false;
```

Does the Angular compiler replace it just with `true`?

[tsc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) does not do; I tried it out.

Comment: You mean when you have this expression the template ?

Comment: Its in the environment.prod.ts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the job of the minifier, noy the compiler.

For example Esbuild (a bundler used by angular) will do that for you:

```
echo '[1].length > 0 ? true : false' | esbuild --loader=ts --minify
> [1].length>0;
```

Comment: You put me on the right track.